# Counting repeated (duplicated) in a list using dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, duplicates

I'm writing a program to identify repeated values and their count in a particular column (named 'StrId') in an Excel spreadsheet. Besides finding repetitions, I need to know how many times each value is repeated.

The Excel data was processed as a list of dictionaries (one dictionary per row) with headers as keys and data as values, like [{'StrId' : 1, 'ProjId' : 358}][{'StrId' : 2, 'ProjId' : 984...}] etc.

My plan was to first identify the 'StrId' keys in each dictionary, put them in a list, and then create another dictionary within that list to pass values and separate when there is more than 1 value, counting those that show up more than once.

Here is my code. Right now, it shows a 'KeyError' message with the fist value, and stops.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('./fullallreadyconversionxmlclean4.xlsx')
sheet = workbook['Full-All']
headers = ["StrId", "ProjectId", "TweetText", "Label"]

excel_data = []
for row_num, row in enumerate(sheet):
    if row_num is 0:
        continue
    row_data = {}
    for col_num, cell in enumerate(row):
        if col_num > len(headers) - 1:
            continue
        key = headers[col_num]
        value = cell.value
        row_data[key] = value
    excel_data.append(row_data)    


for row in excel_data:
    for key in row:    
        if key is 'StrId':
            value = row[key]
            list_ids = []
            list_ids.append(value)

            dup_dic = {}           
            for  value in list_ids:
                if value in list_ids:
                    dup_dic[value] +=1
                else:
                    dup_dic[value] =1                

                print dup_dic
```

Comment: what is the output of `print value` ?

Comment: Is `Projld` relevant to this, or you're trying to find, for example, the number of occurrences of `1` in `Strld` column?

Comment: `print value` shows the list of values for the key. However, after I put the values in `list_ids` they show  'u' (for unicode). I don't know why though

Comment: `ProjId` is not relevant, but it's part of the information converted from Excel to lists of dics

Comment: Why do you have the dicts  inside sublists, can there be more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sublists can contain more than one dict you can flatten the sublists with *itertools.chain* :

```
from collections import Counter
excel_data = [
    [{'StrId': 1, 'ProjId': 358},{'StrId': 5, 'ProjId': 358}],
    [{'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984},{'StrId': 3, 'ProjId': 358}],
    [{'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984}],
    [{'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984}],
]

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
print(Counter(map(itemgetter("StrId"), chain(*excel_data))))
```

But you seem to have a list of dicts so you can remove the chain:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(map(itemgetter("StrId"), excel_data)))
```

Never use if *is* when comparing strings, is checks the identity of and object, use  `==` i.e `if key == 'StrId'` but it would make a lot more sense to just do a lookup i.e   `value = row["StrId"]`. Also give you variables better names, `row` is not a very good name for a *dict*.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. Your code was the best solution for the problem. I'll follow your recommendations as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this. I'm assuming your `excel_data` is structured as a list of lists with one dictionary per list, but let me know if it's not the case.

```
from collections import Counter

excel_data = [
    [{'StrId': 1, 'ProjId': 358}],
    [{'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984}],
    [{'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984}],
    [{'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984}],
]

# create a list of all values
flattened_values = [list_dict[0]['StrId'] for list_dict in excel_data]

# pass them to counter to get a dict of value to count
counter = Counter(flattened_values)  # Counter({2: 3, 1: 1})

# use dictionary comprehension to create a dict from this counter with only
# values with count > 1 to find duplicates
repetitions = {
    val: count for val, count in counter.iteritems() if count > 1
}  # {2: 3}
```

Comment: I get the message `KeyError: 0`, could you tell know why?

Comment: This means your data is not structured as you have posted. Instead of a list of lists, it may be a list of dicts? Please post the actual structure of your data.

Comment: I added the code for structuring my data to the question. I think it's a list of dictionaries, as mentioned in my post. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

excel_data = [
    {'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984},
    {'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984},
    {'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984},
    {'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984},
    {'StrId': 1, 'ProjId': 358},
    {'StrId': 1, 'ProjId': 358},
    {'StrId': 1, 'ProjId': 358},
    {'StrId': 2, 'ProjId': 984},
    {'StrId': 1, 'ProjId': 358},
]

output = defaultdict(int)

for row in excel_data:
    if 'StrId' in row:
        output[row['StrId']] += 1

print output
```

If you got some question about the above code, take a look to [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: This answer works, although it doesn't sort by number of repetitions. Thanks so much.